# Get Automatic Topic Labels from LDA topic model in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, nlp, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

I am doing Topic Modeling in Apache-Spark for Classification of certain products from unstructured data.

So far I have applied Topic modeling (LDA) and getting the topics,but I was wondering if there is any way to automatically infer topic labels from topics given by LDA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDA returns a distribution of the probabilities of each term in the dictionary to represent a specific topic. If you call `describeTopics(n)` on your `LDAModel`, you receive a DataFrame which contains the mapping of term weights to term indices for each topic.

If you need to infer topic labels, I assume you want to obtain human readable terms which represent a specific topic most. However, there is no direct way to get this information from the `LDAModel` for free. Instead, you need to call `describeTopics` on it, and then zip the term indices with your dictionary.

Comment: I have already done what you said there,Now what I want is get a specific label for the Topic words generated by LDA.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly. You already obtained the terms which represent a topic most? Now what kind of labels do you need? Could you please rephrase your question and also post your code.

Comment: Basically I need to do Classification of unseen documents.After Topic Modeling, I need to assign certain labels to the topic terms of a specific topic so that I can classify documents based on that labels.  Code is posted.

Comment: If you want to classify new documents by your trained LDAModel, just transform a dataframe with the new instances by your pipeline model.

Comment: Hey,I was wondering if you are still here. I am thinking to take words from topic model as features and train a classification model and then somehow pass the topic words of test data to that classification model and get the result.